# Job Function just keeps processing without being processed

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create multiple rows in the database table behind the scene in order to decrease page loading time so I am implementing laravel queue for that. But the actual job does not seem to be implementing without any errors

this is in my controller

```
public function store(SlotRequest $request)
{
    $quota = 2;
    $slotquota = request('slotamount') + $quota;

    if ( auth()->user()->wallet->balance < $slotquota ) {

        return Redirect::back()->with('low_balance', 'You do not have a sufficient wallet balance to reserve these SLOTS. Please Load Up Your Wallet');

    } else {

        // Getting SLOTS as objects of an array
        $slotquantity = new SplFixedArray(request('slotamount'));
        $slotquantity = $slotquantity->toArray();
        $user = auth()->user();

        SlotQueuer::dispatch($slotquantity, $user);

    }

        //Sorting Wallet Balance
        $wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        $wallet->balance = $wallet->balance - $slotquota;
        $wallet->save();



        //Returning View With Message
        return Redirect::back()->with('reserved', 'Your SLOTS have been successfully reserved');
}
```

and for my job

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Events\SlotCounter;
use App\Slot;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SlotQueuer implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $slotquantity;
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $slotquantity, $user)
    {
       $this->slotquantity = $slotquantity;
       $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       // Inserting Rows in SLOTS Table
       foreach ($this->slotquantity as $slot) {

        $slot = new Slot();

        $slot->user_id = $this->user->id;

        $slot->save();

        //Slot Counting Event
        event(new SlotCounter);

        }

    }
}
```

I am hoping to create database rows behind the scenes

Comment: please  provide your job class complete code.

Comment: I have provided my job class complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change in your job class

```
protected $slotquantity;
protected $user;

public function __construct($slotquantity , $user)
{
 $this->slotquantity = $slotquantity;
 $this->user = $user;
}
```

In your handle() function

```
public function handle()
{

 // Inserting Rows in SLOTS Table
 foreach ($this->slotquantity as $slot) { //use this keyword to access slotquantity

 $slot = new Slot();

 $slot->user_id = $this->user->id;

 $slot->save();

 //Slot Counting Event
  event(new SlotCounter);

 }

 }
```

Comment: I just tried your idea but now it gives me this error:  Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\SlotQueuer::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\onenaira\app\Http\Controllers\SlotController.php on line 57 does it have something to do with the way my job is being dispatched in my controller?

Comment: okay that was due to my use of SplFixedArray but when i tried the normal array it just kept processing without being processed...I have uploaded my full job class

Comment: open your log file at "storage/log"

Comment: #30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\websites\\onenaira\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 {main}
"} 
i think that is the most recent one

Comment: [2019-04-15 05:02:05] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'id' of non-object at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\websites\\onenaira\\app\\Jobs\\SlotQueuer.php:41)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\websites\\onenaira\\app\\Jobs\\SlotQueuer.php(41): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 41, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Jobs\\SlotQueuer->handle()

Comment: auth()->user()->id , throwing this exception , auth not able that time

Comment: so what do i do to fix this?

Comment: you have to pass user also in job dispatch functionality and handle in job

Comment: how do i do that please?

Comment: i have edited it again check , dispatch(new SlotQueuer($slotquantity, $user));

Comment: you mean declare auth()->user() as a variable then pass as a parameter in dispatch function, declare protected and in job class construct?

Comment: okay now it is actually doing the work but the loop is not ending anymore....just continues to create rows in database table without ending. i will edit my code to the updated one now

Comment: oh i fixed the issue now, problem was i forgot to include the SlotCounter event class, I am going to edit my code again with the right answer